# php a simple math task

Tags: php, arrays

I have the most simple math problem to do that I just can't figure out (probably tired from working all day). It's simple, I loop through items and want to display the final price without the taxes and etc. The thing is that my math is correct, however when I am displaying the prices, all of the items have the same value (the value of the last item). I understand that the total variable is changing everytime I loop and at the last loop is displaying the last value. How to fix that?

```
public function getTotal($items)
{
    $total;
    foreach($items as $item){
        $total = $item->getPrice() - $item->getDiscount() + $item->getValue();
    }
    return $total;
}
```

It should display:

```
Item1: 154
Item2: 77
```

It displays:

```
Item1:77
Item2:77
```

Comment: `$total += $item->getPrice() - $item->getDiscount() + $item->getValue();`

Comment: ^ And don't forget to initialize the `$total` variable with `0`!

Comment: Is  $total is an array

Comment: Thats not what I want. What your code did is counted the total price of ALL products. I want to count the total price of a single product and display it.

Comment: Add square braces in that case

Comment: So what bit of your existing code checks what the product is? Is there a `getProduct()` method? Don't leave us guessing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your whole code is exactly so there's some guessing on my part but have you considered using something like:

```
public function getTotal($item)
{
    return $item->getPrice() - $item->getDiscount() + $item->getValue();
}
```

And then in your method where you output the price you would have:

```
foreach( $items as $item )
{
    // $item->getName() is an wild guess but still you get the point
    echo $item->getName() . ': ' . $this->getTotal( $item );
}
```

Another approach is to store the total price of each item in a new array and then return it:

```
public function getTotals($items)
{
    $totals = array();
    foreach( $items as $item )
    {
        $totals[ $item->getName() ] =  $item->getPrice() - $item->getDiscount() + $item->getValue();
    }
    return $totals;
}
```

And then you would have to just:

```
$totals = $this->getTotals( $items );
foreach( $totals as $name => $totalPrice ) 
{
    echo $name . ': ' . $totalPrice;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You're overwriting the total variable on every iteration. Try the below:

```
public function getTotal($items)
{
$total = 0;
foreach($items as $item){
    $total += $item->getPrice() - $item->getDiscount() + $item->getValue();
}
return $total;
}
```

EDIT:
I understand you wish to see the total for each individual product. What you can do is to return an array instead of a double. For example like this:

```
public function getTotal($items)
{
    $total = array();
    foreach($items as $item){
        $total[] = $item->getPrice() - $item->getDiscount() + $item->getValue();
    }
    return $total;
}
```

Comment: And what if `$items` is empty? In my opinion that should be included

Comment: Hello. I understand what you did but that is not what I want. This code counts the total price of all products. I want to count the total price of a single product.

Comment: @walkingRed: if `$items` is empty 0 will be returned as no iterations will occur.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function getTotal($items)
{
    $total = array();
    foreach($items as $key=>$item){
        $total['Item'.$key] = $item->getPrice() - $item->getDiscount() + $item->getValue();
    }
    return $total;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `[]` which will return a list of arrays it should be like

```
public function getTotal($items)
{
    $total = array();
    foreach($items as $item){
        $total[] = $item->getPrice() - $item->getDiscount() + $item->getValue();
    }
    return $total;// returns an array;
}
```

or can be access as

```
public function getTotal($items)
{
    $total = array();
    foreach($items as $key => $item){
        $total[$key] = $item->getPrice() - $item->getDiscount() + $item->getValue();
    }
    return $total;// returns an array;
}
```